# mvc5 Disable browser back button from certain page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

> How I can disable back button from a certain page ? I tried most examples of JavaScript and non of them is working.

Comment: I used the code below and its not working  <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    setTimeout("disableBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>

Comment: MVC5 I used Sorry for that.

Comment: I found this code <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      

           window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        };
    });
</script>   but it work only when I click on the browser, I need it work while the page in load it.